# Django URL template match (everything except pattern)

Tags: django

I need a django regex that will actually work for the url router to do the following:

Match everything that does not contain "/api" in the route.

The following does not work because django can't reverse (?!

```
r'^(?!api)
```

Answer (score 8):

The usual way to go about this would be to order the route declarations so that the catch-all route is shadowed by the `/api` route, i.e.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^other/', 'views.other', name='other'),
    url(r'^.*$', 'views.catchall', name='catch-all'), 
)
```

Alternatively, if for some reason you really need to skip some routes but cannot do it with the set of regexes supported by Django, you could define a custom pattern matcher class:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLPattern 

class NoAPIPattern(RegexURLPattern):
    def resolve(self, path):
        if not path.startswith('api'):
            return super(NoAPIPattern, self).resolve(path)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^other/', 'views.other', name='other'),
    NoAPIPattern(r'^.*$', 'views.catchall', name='catch-all'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look behind like so:

```
r'^(?!/api).*$'
```

This link explains how to do that:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html

Comment: The OP stated this does not work. The docstring for [normalize](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L46) does indeed state: (6) Raise an error on all other non-capturing (?...) forms (e.g. look-ahead and look-behind matches) and any disjunctive ('|') constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem integrating django with react router, I check this link to fix it.

[decoupled frontend and backend with Django, webpack, reactjs, react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271923/decoupled-frontend-and-backend-with-django-webpack-reactjs-react-router)