# decoupled frontend and backend with Django, webpack, reactjs, react-router

Tags: python, django, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am trying to decouple my frontend and my backend in my project. My frontend is made up of `reactjs` and routing will be done with `react-router`, My backend if made form `Django` and I plan to use the front end to make API (ajax) calls to Django.

Right now I'm not sure how to get these two ends to talk to each other correctly.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/liondancer/django-cherngloong) to my project

Here is my project structure:

```
/cherngloong
  /app (frontend)
  /cherngloong
    /templates
      index.jtml
    urls.py
    settings.py
    ...
  /contact
    urls.py
    views.py
```

I use `webpack` to build all my JS and CSS and place it into `index.html` with `webpack_loader` which looks like this:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

In `Django` here are my `cherngloong/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^api/', include('contact.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I don't want to serve my app from django or make django to serve the same view on ANY url.

Here are my `react-router` routes:

```
var routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={ Views.Layout } >
            <Route path="contact"  component={ Views.Contact }/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={ Views.RouteNotFound } />
    </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

I can currently run the server but when I run the front end portion, I see this in the developer tools

```
http://localhost:8000/static/public/js/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Comment: What URL are you visiting to get that error to show up on the developer tools?

Comment: See my previous answer for this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216827/django-static-files-wont-load/10243622#10243622)

Comment: @user2719875 `localhost:8000/`

Comment: @krs thanks for your help. Unfortunately I tried your suggestion of adding `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` however I am still getting the same error =[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `settings.py` defines the following:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app'),
)
```

This will serve the files in `/app/` directory. so the url `/static/public/js/` translates to the `/app/public/js/` directory.

What you want is to serve the files in the `/public/` dir. Use the following settings:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'js/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json')
    }
}
```

---

Also, the urls are different in the code you posted here and in github. The `url(r'', Templa...` will match ALL urls and just render `index.html` even when making calls to `/api/`. Move this line to the bottom:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('contact.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```